Laravel 11 Storage URL not triggering Middleware
I have a storage url that can be opened and it looks like this
<a href="{{ Storage::url('invoices/'. $invoice->invoice_number . '.pdf')  }}?is_opened={{ $token }}" class="f-fallback button button--blue" target="_blank">View Invoice</a>

The intended action should be a custom middleware running when this link is opened. Whenever i click the button, the middleware is ignored. I have the middleware set up correctly as it runs on every single page without any issues.
Question: Does middleware not affect storage URLs?

Static files are served by the webserver directly so will not run any PHP code. You might need to create a "download" route that uses a download response instead of linking to the file directly (also if this is to add some sort of security to the file then you might need to move it out of a publicly accessed URL)

Files placed in the storage/ folder are called directly so middleware won't be called when you access them.
If you want to use middleware while downloading/accessing something from the storage/ folder, you can make a separate route and then apply middleware to it.
